# Не отображает картинку

Tags: php, mysql

Не выводит картинку из БД. Все выводит, кроме картинки.

```
 <?php
    include '../core/init.php';

    $id = (int)$_GET['user_id'];
    if($id == 0)
     exit('Ид пользователя не передан');
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`='".$id."'" ));
    if(!isset($row['user_id']))
     exit('Пользователя в базе нет');
    echo '<img src="', $row['profile'], '"';

    ?>
```

Comment: - нет закрывающего уголка > у тэга img ?  
- работа завершается на строчке ` exit('Пользователя в базе нет');` ?

Comment: да оно завершается на этом 
когда я поставил >  echo '<img src="', $row['profile'], '">';
картинка по прежднему не отображается, только теперь появился значок что картинки нет

Comment: неверный путь к картинке

Comment: в одного пользователя открывается, во всех остальных нет, даже если загрузить одну и ту же всем!

Comment: Укажите абсолютный путь к файлу, а не относительный.  
Например, если свою картинку подгружает `index.php` то путь к картинке ` images/profile/82225076e9.jpg`  
если картинку другого пользователя подгружает например `user/info.php` то путь к картинке `user/images/profile/82225076e9.jpg`

Comment: user/images/profile/82225076e9.jpg так я делал, если вручную создать и поместить туда фотки, во первых это надо делать вручную, во вторых места у два раза больше жрет

Comment: [Прочтите]( http://codingtools.ru/lessons/1/72)

Answer (score 1):

А чему равно `$row['profile']`?

Возможно, не правильный путь к картинке.

Comment: тогда почему одного пользователя выводит, а остальных трех нет? в картинок всех одинаков формат

Comment: это ты на локалке пробуешь?
не на хостинге?

Comment: да на локалке

Comment: плохо.
а в БД там точно есть что-нибудь?
и посмотри HTML, что там он вывел

Comment: а точно есть данное изображение?

Comment: добавьте слеш перед images

Comment: сейчас немного не понял)
в каком браузере тестишь?

Comment: echo '<img src="/' . $row['profile'] . '">';

Comment: почитайте про абсолютные и относительные пути, и не морочьте голову, ни себе ни сообществу.

Comment: Какие адреса в адресной строке при выдающейся картинке и не выдающейся? Скопируйте их сюда оба.  
Или нажмите правой кнопкой мыши на иконке, копировать адрес картинки, вставить сюда в комментарий. Так же оба адреса.

Comment: вот и ладненько, а то я уже было начал сомневаться в Ваших способностях к самостоятельному чтению, после того как Вам уже трижды на это указали.

Comment: а ты не сомневайся, я разберусь без вас и ваших "высококвалифицированных" гуру которые могу только ссылками расбрасыватся, раз здесь такие все ЗНАТОКИ то тему можно разкрывать без вашего участия решил!

Comment: :) Ну и как решилась проблема?

Comment: По той ссылке текста на два абзаца. Проще один раз изучить азы, чем потом каждый раз натыкаться на одни и теже грабли в разных вариациях.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<img src="', $row['profile'], '"';
```

А почему переменная в запятых? Должны быть точки:

```
echo '<img src="'. $row['profile']. '"';
```

Comment: [Прочтите]( http://php.net/manual/ru/function.echo.php).  
Так можно делать.

Comment: спасибо, никогда не встречал

Comment: без разницы в чем она, главное уже решил